# How to use sin(_ : ) with a FloatingPoint value in Swift 3

Tags: generics, floating-point, swift3

```
 import Foundation
 public func sine <T: FloatingPoint   > (_ x: T  ) -> T{
    return sin(x)
 }
 // Error: Cannot invoke 'sin' with an argument list of type '(T)'
```

Is there a way around this? 
Many thanks.

Comment: @LeoDabus thank you for your suggestion. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a sin method that accepts FloatingPoint type also as follow:

```
import UIKit

func sin<T: FloatingPoint>(_ x: T) -> T {
    switch x {
    case let x as Double:
        return sin(x) as? T ?? 0
    case let x as CGFloat:
        return sin(x) as? T ?? 0
    case let x as Float:
        return sin(x) as? T ?? 0
    default:
        return 0 as T
    }
}
```

Another option is adding a method or a computed property extension to FloatingPoint type as follow:

```
extension FloatingPoint {
    var sin: Self {
        switch self {
        case let x as Double:
            return UIKit.sin(x) as? Self ?? 0
        case let x as CGFloat:
            return UIKit.sin(x) as? Self ?? 0
        case let x as Float:
            return UIKit.sin(x) as? Self ?? 0
        default:
            return 0 as Self
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Leo :)

Comment: You can remove the first set of forced downcasts by using a conditional type-casting pattern – `case let x as Double` etc.

Comment: This switching and casting adds a lot of branching at run time. That could have pretty severe performance implications, which can be pretty important in functions like `sin`, which are often really often called.