# How to write a generic function for floating point values in swift

Tags: swift, generics, floating-point, protocols

I would like to call floating point methods on floating point types in swift.

```
func example<T : FloatingPoint>(_ x:T) -> T {
    return cos(cbrt(x + 1))
}
```

Is there a better way to do so than this?

```
protocol SupportsFloatingPoint : FloatingPoint {
    var cubeRoot:Self { get }
    var cosine:Self { get }
}

extension Double : SupportsFloatingPoint {
    var cubeRoot:Double { return Darwin.cbrt(self) }
    var cosine:Double { return Darwin.cos(self) }
}

extension Float : SupportsFloatingPoint {
    var cubeRoot:Float { return Darwin.cbrt(self) }
    var cosine:Float { return Darwin.cos(self) }
}

func cbrt<T : SupportsFloatingPoint>(_ x:T) -> T {
    return x.cubeRoot
}

func cos<T : SupportsFloatingPoint>(_ x:T) -> T {
    return x.cosine
}

func example<T : SupportsFloatingPoint>(_ x:T) -> T {
    return cos(cbrt(x - 1))
}
```

Note that the addition operator is lost here.  You can do `-`, `*` and `/` but not `+` on SupportsFloatingPoint types.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39283419/how-to-use-sin-with-a-floatingpoint-value-in-swift-3/39283903#39283903

Answer (score 3):

`Generic Math(s) Functions` were proposed in SE-0246, and accepted with modifications. The implementation is currently blocked by some other factors.

In the meanwhile, you can access the same functionality from the [`Numerics`](https://github.com/apple/swift-numerics) library hosted  on Apple's own GitHub page, and distributed with the Swift Package Manager.

## Original Answer

You don't *need* a new protocol. You can extend the existing `FloatingPoint` protocol for supported types:

```
// Just for fun :)
prefix operator √
prefix operator ∛

extension FloatingPoint where Self == Double {
    var squareRoot: Self { return sqrt(self) }
    var cubeRoot: Self { return cbrt(self) }
    var sine: Self { return sin(self) }
    var cosine: Self { return cos(self) }

    static prefix func √(_ x: Self) -> Self { return x.squareRoot }
    static prefix func ∛(_ x: Self) -> Self { return x.cubeRoot }
}

extension FloatingPoint where Self == Float {
    var squareRoot: Self { return sqrt(self) }
    var cubeRoot: Self { return cbrt(self) }
    var sine: Self { return sin(self) }
    var cosine: Self { return cos(self) }

    static prefix func √(_ x: Self) -> Self { return x.squareRoot }
    static prefix func ∛(_ x: Self) -> Self { return x.cubeRoot }
}

print(Double.pi.cosine)
print(√25.0)
print(∛8.0)
```

Admittedly, there's a lot of code duplication, which I'm currently investigating how to minimize. On the bright side, at least this is all static, inlineable code that'll produce very fast machine code.